# @NonNull usage when null check is in another method/class

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-support-library

I am trying to abstract some common checks for an Android library and add Nullability annotations at the same time but I am getting a warning.

Let's say I have an example method in this library:

```
 public int method(@Nullable final String param) {
    final int precheckResult = LibPrechecks.checkForMethod(param); // Does check for param not being null
    if (LibPrechecks.checksFailed(precheckResult)) {
      return precheckResult;
    }

    // Rest of logic
    return internalMethod(param); // IDE is complaining that param cannot be null
  }
```

That then calls another internal method of the library for some processing:

```
     private int internalMethod(@NonNull String param) {
        // processing logic

        return 0;
      }
```

And here is an example "precheck" class:

```
public class LibPrechecks {

  public static int checkForMethod(@Nullable final String param) {
    if (param  == null) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public static boolean checksFailed(final int precheckResult) {
    return precheckResult < 0;
  }
}
```

I am returning an error code upon a null so I know it's safe and non-null by the time the internal method is called with the param, but the IDE is still unhappy and thinks the param could be null.  How would I fix the warning in Android Studio and do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE doesn’t know what `checkForMethod()` or `checksFailed()` do, so you need to either suppress the warning or write some code that the IDE can statically analyze to prove that `param` is not null.

I think the best thing to do would be to assert that `param` is not null after the precheck code is done running. Either

```
assert param != null;
```

or

```
if (param == null) throw new AssertionError();
```

will work.